# Got must be real number, not BadRequest error when I am trying to return http error

Tags: python, backend, foreman, quart

I am building a python api using quart, and using foreman to run it. When I am trying to return some error code, it does not run correctly but returns a html and tells me it needs to be real number, not bad request.
My code looks like this for getting all info of a game from DB

```
@app.route("/games/info/<int:game_id>", methods=["GET"])
async def display_game_info(game_id):
    db = await _get_db()
    try:
        data = await db.fetch_all(
            "SELECT * FROM GameStats where game_id = :game_id;",
            values={"game_id": game_id},
        )
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        abort(409,e)
    if data == []:
        abort(400,{"error":"game not exist!"})
#.........
# modify format and return
# ……
```

If I enter a game ID that exists, it would return the correct result, but if I try to enter a game_id that does not exist, it would return a long HTML that contains the error message. In this case, within the long HTML returned, I can find

```
<h1>TypeError <span>must be real number, not BadRequest</span></h1>
```

My 400 error handler is like this

```
@app.errorhandler(400)
def bad_request(e):
    return {"error": str(e)}, 400
```

I have tried to see which line gets the error, and everything works fine before

```
abort(400,{"error":"game not exist!"})
```

How can I fix this error?

Just figured it out.
Changing

```
return {"error": str(e)}, 400
```

to

```
return {"error": e.description}, 400
```

can solve the issue. Seems this error happens because str has some issue with converting werkzeug.exceptions class object to string.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I just tried it, and everything goes well before calling error handler 400

Comment: I can't run code, so I can't test it and I can't see what is the problem. Better create `minimal working code` which we could copy and test.

Comment: I just figured it out. Changing str(e) to e.description can solve the issue. This happens because str failed to convert the error message to string.

Comment: you could put it as answer below - maybe it will be useful for someone else. And later you can mark your answer as accepted - and this will mean problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Changing

```
return {"error": str(e)}, 400
```

to

```
return {"error": e.description}, 400
```

can solve the issue. Seems this error happens because str has some issue with converting werkzeug.exceptions class object to string.